# authorization with python requests

Tags: python-requests

there's next site - vten.ru
When I try to make GET request with Postman to it, I give in return status code 304 Not Modified.
Code on Phyton:

```
import requests

url = "http://vten.ru"

payload = ""
headers = {
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "29ae741a-1c31-4a52-b10e-4486cb0d6eb7"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

how can I get the page?

Comment: @Fozoro what happened?

Comment: On a side note, if you want to test requests, you should consider [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) instead

Comment: @Nino Filiu so now i use Postman but what's wrong? I'm trying to make GET request but I give in return 304 status code, what does it mean, answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably already have a version of the request cached, hence the "Not Modified" response indicating that the response hasn't changed since you last requested it.

**EDIT:**
Viewing that site/inspecting the network activity via Chrome shows that the document returned is actually `http://m.vten.ru`. You should try making your GET request to that URL instead.

You also need to add the `Accept: text/html` header to your request. That returns the page you want having just tested it locally.

Comment: but how can I solve it? maybe clear cache or something?

Comment: that's what I want to know

Comment: See my edit. Works in Postman for me locally using the Accept: text/html header.